# Macbook Pro gets slow frequently when connected to external monitor via HDMI cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

Hi I have a Macbook Pro (2019). Both my laptop and external monitor is getting slow frequently when i connect to a LG 4k external monitor. I am using typec to Hdmi adpater to connect to monitor.

My Laptop details:
[image]

Also when this happens videos are getting pixelated (can be seen in the below image).
[image]

All I can see is that my kernal_task is consuming too much cpu but not sure why this is happening.
[image]

I have took some screenshots of temperatures from tg_pro app when this issue occurred, and it seems fine.
[image]
[image]

Any Idea, How I can fix the issue?

Comment: What else is connected to your system? The left ports on MBPs lead to more thermal throttling, although this seems not the issue here, I would try to (only) use the right ports, especially for anything power related. Further, that screenshot might indicate hardware failure. To rule out software you *could* do a clean install, but be sure to have a good backup. First though, I would also try to boot into safe mode, reset NVRAM/PRAM and SMC and check if that problem persists. Can you narrow down the issue to some activity or app that is causing this? Does this **only** happen with the monitor?

Comment: Yeah, this happens only with monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. I cannot provide any reference links but a colleague of mine suggested to enable h264ify codec instead of vp8/vp9. Apparently it seems to be working to an extent.

h264ify can be enabled from the following [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/h264ify/aleakchihdccplidncghkekgioiakgal?hl=en) in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you have a faulty cable and I would look into replacing that immediately. The faulty cable is also causing the performance issues as kernel_task with such a high CPU usage means it is thermal throttling *hard*.

I've always used the Choetech brand for my USB-C to HDMI but PrimeCables will do as well. Make sure you're getting something rated for 4K 60Hz and check the reviews on whatever you intend to buy. As an aside, I'd look into a USB-C to DP adapter instead as this can result in a better experience with certain monitors.

Comment: I am using an official apple typec to hdmi adapter only

Comment: Can you test with another monitor?

Comment: currently i don't have another monitor. The setup was working fine when i connect another macbook pro using same cable. So i ruled out monitor and cable failure

Comment: I assume that you've tried NVRAM/PRAM resets?

Comment: yep, but resetting them doesn't resolve the issue